# Error creating virtualenv in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

I have installed Cygwin on my Win7 box; also I installed python2.7, setuptools, easy_install, pip, etc...
I installed virtualenv and virtaulenvwrapper using easy_install.

The problem is that, when I try now to create a virtualenv, I get the following:

```
    $ mkvirtualenv --distribute --no-site-packages --python=/usr/bin/python2.7.exe temp
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7.exe
New python executable in temp/bin/python2.7
Also creating executable in temp/bin/python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 2560, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 964, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1065, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.8.4-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 1506, in install_python
    raise e
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I also tried not using any option, just `mkvirtualenv temp` but it I got exactly the same error.
I also created a symbolic link between python2.7.exe and python.exe.... again, no luck.

I searched online but I can't figure it out....any idea???

Comment: how did you install python2.7? If that windows python or cygwin python?

Comment: that would be cygwin python. I installed it through the normal cygwin installer, that allows for python 2.6 or 2.7. I selected the latter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is broken for cygwin in version 1.8.3 and 1.8.4. Using an older version would solve the problem.

If you do not want to use older versions, the current develop branch of the git repository (https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv) is working fine. This command would give you that:

`pip install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/develop`

or

`easy_install https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/tarball/develop`

This would in theory mean the next release, which should be 1.8.5, will also have the problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer, but this solved my problem: 
[Link](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-12/msg00141.html)

Clearly there is a bug in the latest version, so rolling back to a previous one is not such a bad thing, at least if you're using Cygwin as I am.